# Image resize overflows css grid column in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, grid-layout, image-resizing

I have a grid with two cells. The first contains an image that resize its width according to the height cell. This cell have the width of the image. Second cell has a width to fill remain space.
In Chrome, image resize its size according to cell height and first cell expand its width according to its content. But in Firefox image overflow the container and cell width is not expanded. How can I fix it?

I have found a post with the same problem: [CSS Grid template with image breaks Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447154/css-grid-template-with-image-breaks-firefox)

```css
      .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
      }

      .fixed {
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        min-width: max-content;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
      }

      .remain {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }

      input:checked ~ .container > .remain {
        height: 200px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" />Select to increase .remain height
    <div class="container">
      <div class="fixed"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/24x24/fff700" /></div>
      <div class="remain"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification